# MySQL values being inflated significantly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

I have a query that is intended to fetch the value of enquiries for each day of the current month.

The problem I am having is that the numbers are way too large.

Here is my query:

```
$M = date('m');
$Y = date('Y');
$SQL = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(enquiries.dateCreated, '%D') AS name,
            SUM((SELECT SUM(PE.quantity * PE.net) FROM parts_enquiries PE WHERE PE.enquiryId = enquiries.id)) AS y
            FROM enquiries
            WHERE MONTH(enquiries.dateCreated) = $M
            AND YEAR(enquiries.dateCreated) = $Y
            AND enquiries.archived = 0
            GROUP BY DAY(enquiries.dateCreated)";
```

There can be 0 or more enquiries per day and there can be 1 or more parts per enquiry.

Does anyone know where my query is going wrong?

Comment: What does `$filter` look like?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have removed it as it was empty and I simplified the query (removed entities)/

Comment: Your current query is unlikely to use any indices containing `dateCreated` (due to the use of the given functions).  It'd be better to use conditions of the form `dateColumn >= $startOfCurrentMonth AND dateColumn < $startOfNextMonth`, as [explained in this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) (it's covering SQL Server, but the concepts still apply).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. How else would I get the month of the enquiries to compare to $M?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will make a difference, but try running this just using explicit `join`s, no subqueries, no implicit joins:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(enquiries.dateCreated, '%D') AS name,
       SUM(PE.quantity * PE.net) AS y
FROM enquiries JOIN
     entities
     ON enquiries.entityId = entities.id JOIN
     parts_enquiries PE
     ON PE.enquiryId = enquiries.id
WHERE MONTH(enquiries.dateCreated) = $M AND
      YEAR(enquiries.dateCreated) = $Y AND
      enquiries.archived = 0
       $filter
GROUP BY DAY(enquiries.dateCreated);
```

One possibility is that `$filter` is set to something with an `OR` in it.  A safer way to write this is:

```
WHERE MONTH(enquiries.dateCreated) = $M AND
      YEAR(enquiries.dateCreated) = $Y AND
      enquiries.archived = 0
      (1=1 AND $filter)
```

Comment: Sadly not, exactly same results :(. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @imperium2335 . . . Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Also, add in what `$filter` is, if it is set.